# A variable is null eventhough i have already set it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying to make my enemies move using A* Pathfinding project (following 
Brackeys's tutorial, which can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvtFUfJ6CP8&t)).

In my `Start()` method, I use `InvokeRepeating("GeneratePath", 0f, .5f);`

```cs
void GeneratePath()
    {
        if (seeker.IsDone())
            seeker.StartPath(rb.position, Game.currentPlayer.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position, OnPathComplete);
    }
```

Then:

```cs
void OnPathComplete(Path p)
    {
        if (!p.error)
        {
            path = p;
            currentWayPoint = 0;
        }
    }
```

Notice that my `path` variable has been set.

In my `Update()` method:

```cs
public void MoveAI()
    {
        if (Game.currentPlayer == null || path == null) return;

        if (currentWayPoint >= path.vectorPath.Count)
        {
            reachEndOfPath = true;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            reachEndOfPath = false;
        }

        Vector2 dir = ((Vector2)path.vectorPath[currentWayPoint] - rb.position).normalized;
        Vector2 force = dir * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        rb.AddForce(force);

        float distance = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, path.vectorPath[currentWayPoint]);

        if (distance < nextWaypointDistance)        
            currentWayPoint++;                    
    }
```

Since it's on my `Update()` method, my enemies should move.
But they don't.

I set a breakpoint and confirmed that `path` is indeed null.

How though? I had already set it.

Edit: I did move the two

```
path = p;
currentWayPoint = 0;
```

outside of the if statement (to see if the problem was `p.error`) and `path` is still null.

Comment: It is ony set when p.error is false. You should investigate that.

Comment: @JeroenHeier read the updated post :)

Comment: Should `OnPathComplete` pass a variable of type Path in your start function?

Comment: @ThomasByy I was just following the tutorial. I was wondering why he didn't pass it, but it worked in his video,so....

Comment: Is the first implementation of the tutorial working? The one with AIPath + AIDestinationSetter? If not it's just a matter of setting up the grid correctly (happeing at [this point of the tutorial](https://youtu.be/jvtFUfJ6CP8?t=157))

Comment: i could try but it wont work my case. The target is an instantiated game object (you can see it on the ```MoveAI()``` script, ```Game.currentPlayer```). I can't just drag it in. So if my enemies does move, it wont have a target.

Comment: About the grid, I think I should have done it correctly? When I scan it, it does recognise my wall and stuff.